# Python Side by side box plots after groupby in Matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, group-by, boxplot

Need to do a group by and print 2 boxplots side by side. In the example below I need to plot boxplots for column A by grouping its values by column B.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,1), columns=['A'])
df['B'] = [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1]
for n, grp in df.groupby('B'):
   plt.boxplot(x='A',data=grp)
```

Current output[image]

desired output - Something Like:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a position to the call to `plt.boxplot()` to avoid that the boxplot will be drawn twice at the same position:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 1), columns=['A'])
df['B'] = [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1]
for n, grp in df.groupby('B'):
    plt.boxplot(x='A', data=grp, positions=[n])
plt.xticks([1, 2], ['Label 1', 'Label 2'])
plt.show()
```

[image: boxplot from groupby]

Or you could use seaborn let the grouping. You can replace the numbers in the column to have labels.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 1), columns=['A'])
df['B'] = [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1]
df['B'] = df['B'].replace({1: 'Label 1', 2: 'Label 2'})
sns.boxplot(data=df, x='B', y='A' )
plt.show()
```

[image: seaborn boxplot]

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how I can set tick labels for both plots?

Comment: You can use `plt.xticks([1, 2], ['Label 1', 'Label 2'])` (or `ax.set_xticklabels(['Label 1', 'Label 2'])` with the object-oriented API).